# Coordinate Rings and Dedekind Domains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

I am relatively new to ring theory, though I have an idea of what things kind of are. I have been learning about Dedekind domains, which are integral domains which are Noetherian, integrally closed and where every prime ideal is maximal. I have also heard that for non-singular curves such as $y^2 = x^3 - x$, the coordinate ring $k[x, y] / \langle y^2 - x^3 + x \rangle$ is a Dedekind domain, where the conditions of not having zero divisors roughly correponds to not having nodes, integrally closed corresponds to not having nodes, and Noetherian corresponds to things being finite (I believe this is related to divisors? Which I have heard of but do not understand well enough).

I tried looking up references on this, but it seems that people mostly state this as a "see this interesting correspondence!" example to ring theory beginners. Therefore, I was wondering if anyone could make this more specific, i.e. how the algebraic geometry concepts coincide with the purely algebraic side, especially the condition of being integrally closed, as it seems completely random to me from the algebraic perspective as well. Any specific references will also be great (for ring theory but also for the geometry).

Also a slightly different question, but can someone provide an example of an integral domain which is Noetherian and with Krull dimension $1$, but does not have unique prime ideal factorisation? As I mentioned, I can't "conceptually understand" this condition at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For your last question the condition is that every ideal factors as a product of prime ideals ($(2)\subset \Bbb{Z}[2i]$,and $(x^2)\subset \Bbb{Q}[x^2,x^3]$ fail to do so), that this factorization is unique is a bonus. In a non-Noetherian domain (a maximal ideal of the algebraic integers) it may be that $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$ which is a non-unique factorization.

Comment: The coordinate ring is a domain off the curve is irreducible, and it is noetherian because it is a quotient of a polynomial ring by definition. Integral closure corresponds to the geometric notion of normality (it is not easy to see why this is a geometric notion, really, but it is. It is explained in Eisenbud and Harris's book on schemes) For curves, normality is the same as non singularity, though, and that is clearly a geometric thing.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/109395/1409 discusses the geometric content of normality.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your examples! I imagine that the second one is related to $\mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^3] \cong \mathbb{Q}[X, Y] / \langle Y^2 - X^3 \rangle$. Also just to confirm, is my reasoning correct that $\langle x^2 \rangle$ is not a prime ideal because we can rephrase it as $\langle X \rangle \subset \mathbb{Q}[X, Y] / \langle Y^2 - X^3 \rangle$, which does not hold because $\langle X \rangle$ does not contain $\langle Y^2 - X^3 \rangle$? (I believe there is a result where a prime ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is a prime ideal in $R / \mathfrak{p}$ iff $\mathfrak{a} \supset \mathfrak{p}$).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your explanation! I will try to digest that, it explains a lot of my questions.

Comment: @reuns And can you explain why your first example is not a product of prime ideals? In fact, isn't $\langle 2 \rangle$ a prime ideal, since if two elements $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[2i] \setminus \langle 2 \rangle = \{(2a + 1) + 2bi : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, then their product will have odd real part and hence not be in $\langle 2 \rangle$.

Comment: The prime ideal is $(2,2i)$. Check that $(2i)^2 \in (2)$ but $2i\not \in (2)$

Comment: @reuns Oh! I didn't realise $2i \notin \langle 2 \rangle$. That is very interesting :) Thanks